# libusb errors when trying to redirect usb webcam with xfreerdp

Tags: usb, permissions, webcam, udev, rdp

Having difficulty redirecting my logitech webcam/mic with xfreerdp. I keep getting access errors from libusb despite udev rules that should give my plugdev group (of which I'm a member) access to the device.  I can load microphone or audio pass-through just fine but this continued to fail. Anyone familiar with what I'm missing here?

Errors from xfreerdp output

```
user@ubuntu$ xfreerdp /loglevel:DEBUG /usb:id,dev:046d:0892 [...truncated...]
[21:37:42:540] [21547:21548] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.rdpsnd.client] - [static] Loaded fake backend for rdpsnd
[21:37:42:540] [21547:21548] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.drdynvc.client] - Loading Dynamic Virtual Channel urbdrc
[21:37:42:542] [21547:21548] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - VID: 0x046D, PID: 0x0892
[21:37:42:542] [21547:21548] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - libusb_open: error LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS[-3]
[21:37:42:542] [21547:21548] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - **libusb_open [b=0x01,p=0x02,a=0x18,VID=0x046D,PID=0x0892]: error LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS[-3]**
```

Some basic information about versions, udev rules, device output is included below. I added the 90-usbperms.rules file today, reloaded udev rules, and unplugged/replugged the webcam but still get the errors above. I've enabled/disabled a few entries in policy on my windows 10 host to ensure my host wasn't blocking functionality like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719489/how-to-enable-usb-redirection-in-windows-10/46628854

```
user@ubuntu$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa"

user@ubuntu$ dpkg -l libusb*
||/ Name               Version          Architecture Description
+++-==================-================-============-=====================================
ii  libusb-0.1-4:amd64 2:0.1.12-32      amd64        userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0:amd64 2:1.0.23-2build1 amd64        userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0:i386  2:1.0.23-2build1 i386         userspace USB programming library

user@ubuntu$ lsusb | grep Orb
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam

user@ubuntu$ xfreerdp /version
This is FreeRDP version 2.2.0 (n/a)

user@ubuntu$ cat /etc/udev.rules.d/90-usbperms.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",GROUP="plugdev",MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d",ATTRS{idProduct}=="0892",GROUP="plugdev",TAG+="uaccess"SYMLINK+="webcam"

user@ubuntu$ grep plugdev /etc/group
plugdev:x:46:user
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your udev rule (last line)

> user@ubuntu$ cat /etc/udev.rules.d/90-usbperms.rules
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb",GROUP="plugdev",MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d",ATTRS{idProduct}=="0892",GROUP="plugdev",**TAG+="uaccess"SYMLINK+="webcam"**

first correct it - it should be:

> **TAG+="uaccess", SYMLINK+="webcam"**

then check the device existence via symlink and which permissions and ownership it has:

```
$ ls -al /dev/webcam
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root plugdev 189, 0 12-25 03:17 /dev/webcam
```

*before the check you may need to reload udev rules

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```